knife_project in Blender 4.2 (code)
I'm trying to use knife_project to subtract one mesh from another in Blender 4.2. I had it working in Blender 3.1, but after upgrading to 4.2 it no longer works. I get to the line where knife_project is called, and there I get an exception. If I remember correctly I think it was RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh. Trying other older suggestions here I still don't get it to work. Does anyone have a working example on using knife_project in Blender 4.2?
Here is my code:
def cookie_cut(dough, cutter):
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = dough

        if bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

        dough.select_set(False)
        if type(cutter) is tuple:
            for c in cutter:
                c.select_set(True)
        elif cutter.type == 'MESH':
            cutter.select_set(True)

        region, rv3d, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)

        # context override dictionary 
        override = {
            'scene'            : bpy.context.scene,
            'region'           : region,
            'area'             : area,
            'space'            : v3d,
            'active_object'    : bpy.context.object,
            'window'           : bpy.context.window,
            'screen'           : bpy.context.screen,
            'selected_objects' : bpy.context.selected_objects,
            'edit_object'      : bpy.context.object
        }

        # top view
        oldRot = rv3d.view_rotation
        oldLoc = rv3d.view_location
        oldDist = rv3d.view_distance
        oldPersp = rv3d.view_perspective

        rv3d.view_rotation = mathutils.Euler( (0,0,0) ).to_quaternion()
        rv3d.view_location = (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0)
        rv3d.view_distance = 1000
        rv3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'

        # redraw the scene
        bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)

        bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(override)

        bpy.ops.mesh.separate()

        rv3d.view_rotation = oldRot
        rv3d.view_location = oldLoc
        rv3d.view_distance = oldDist
        rv3d.view_perspective = oldPersp

        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    except:
        print("Problem in cookie_cut!")

    return {'FINISHED'}


So, I'm trying to solve the problem by using boolean modifier instead. It works fine when the cutter is a single polygon.  I first fill the cutter polygon and add a solidify modifier. Then I add a boolean modifier to the dough and apply it. The problem is that this approach doesn't work straightforward when the cutter consists of several polygons (think islands). I would have to do this operation separately for every polygon, and then I can't seem to combine the results together correctly. Could someone share a similar working example?

This will knife project from the orthographic top view in 4.2:
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area, region=area.regions[-1]):
            bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type="TOP")
            bpy.data.objects["cutter"].select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(cut_through=True)

